# Dynamics Ax 2012 R3 system label dont change

Tags: label, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I will change language but some sys labels dont change. especially File menu and right click. What can I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are we confusing the language options of the client interface (Microsoft Dynamics AX / Tools / Options) with that of the Label manager (Microsoft Dynamics AX / Tools / Development tools / Label)?

Comment: @ian_scho thank you for interest.Turkish language translate word at en-au than I selected en-au in tools/ options/ general but I cant find tools/development tools/label. you can see screenshot at above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We were able to solve this problem with the help of André Arnaud de Calavon in [this thread](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/205195/534436#534436)

From the link:

> These labels are part of the KTD files. You can find them in the BIN
>   directory of the clients and the server (e.g. axSYSen-us.ktd).